# Sinatra Ruby iterate over an array in a hash to send jQuery Sortable to database

Tags: ruby, sinatra, jquery-ui-sortable

I've isolated my lack of knowledge down to this snipit I keep tweaking in irb.
I'm trying to use jQuery's UI Sortable to send a post to the database, so far I can get it to send the update but it sends the entire array instead of each array item at a time.
It's amazing that I have not found one post yet with someone trying Sinatra and Sortable. Hmmm

## Hash and sinatra code

```
superslide = {"weee"=>["3", "4", "1", "2"]}

moo = Sort.all
moo.each do |o|

    o.sortorder = superslide['weee']
    puts o.sortorder

end
#Output 
3412
3412
3412
3412
```

Above you can see it groups the arrays values into one line for each loop. I know there's a Ruby elementary thing i'm missing.

Below is the Rails equivalent I ultimately would like to clone to Sinatra, but little things screw up there as well, the

```
.index(book.id.to_s) + 1
```

throws an error, I guess since its a string, I tried to_i but it just edits the same group of numbers.

## Rails code to translate

```
def sort
@books = Book.all
@books.each do |book|
book.position = params['book'].index(book.id.to_s) + 1
book.save
end
```

http://practiceovertheory.com/blog/2009/08/07/sortable-lists-with-jquery-in-rails/

I have also tested iterating the array in the hash like so, forgive the different names, I have a lot of test routes I can't make sence of now with test code.

```
 slideNum.sortorder = params['slide'].each do |k,v| 
   k.each { |x| puts x }

 end
```

## jQuery Sortable if you need it

```
var foo = $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            update: function(event, ui){
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                    //  data: $('#books').sortable('serialize'),
                        data: foo.sortable("serialize",{key:'bunny[]'}),
                        dataType: 'script',
                        url: '/sort'
                });
            },
            change: function(){console.log(foo.sortable("serialize",{key:'bunny[]'}))}      
        });
```

## Needed output, I am assuming.

I want it to fire its update method and save the one hash=>key[]=>value
So I guess the output would be, using an even simpler setup

```
superslide = {"weee"=>["3", "4", "1", "2"]}


superslide.each do |o|

    ai = superslide['weee']
    puts ai
  puts "event"
end
```

#### Wanted output

```
3
event
4
event
2
event
1
event
```

#### Current not wanted output

```
Instead of 
3
4
2
1
event
```

## Update

In Sinatra i'm trying to save datafilenumber in this case like

```
datafilenumber.save = wee[0] # =1
datafilenumber.save = wee[1] # =2
etc…
```

#### updated test

```
superslide = {"weee"=>["3", "4", "1", "2"]}
 superslide.each do |o|

  ai = superslide['weee']
  datafilenumber = ai.each {|x|  "#{x}"}
  puts "box + #{datafilenumber}"  
end

#Outputs
box + 3412
```

## Sinatra Route

Currently Outputs numbers and saves to database but its the same number, so all slides become that one value. Getting close!

```
post '/sort' do
  sortall = Sort.all

  slidevar = params['slide']

  slidevar.each do |k,v|
    k.each do |x|
      sortall.update(:sortorder => x)
      puts x
      puts v.object_id
    end     
  end

end
```

## Testing with inspect and class

```
slidevar = params['slide']
puts params.inspect #    {"slide"=>["3", "2", "1", "4"]}
puts params.class #    Hash
puts slidevar.inspect #    ["3", "2", "1", "4"]
puts slidevar.class #    Array
```

Comment: What should this output? You have the Rails equivalent, but I'm not seeing the relation between your Sinatra attempt and the Rails example.

Comment: I've updated the above post at the bottom for the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? (based on your update)

```
superslide = {"weee"=>["3", "4", "1", "2"]}
superslide.each do |k,ai|      # |key, value| i.e. |"weee", ["3", "4", "1", "2"]|
  ai.each do |x|               # will give you "3", "4", "1", "2" on iterations
    datafilenumber.save = x    # not sure what this was in your update
    # do whatever other actions you need to do
  end
end
```

It's still a little tough to tell what you want because your two updates are a little different, but I think what you need to make better use of iterators for your hash and the contained array. This gets you ready to create your "Wanted Output" you gave. Hope this helps.

Edit based on your most recent update. I think you meant to iterate over `v` in line 5 of the new code. I'm assuming that `slidevar` is the same hash you were dealing with before (`superslide`).

Edit #2: Look closely at your inspection code. You are inspecting `params`, a hash, and then `params['slide']`, an array. However, your code treats `params['slide']` as a hash itself. (Or I got confused throughout your sets of code. But either way this should work :)

```
post '/sort' do
  sortall = Sort.all
  # slidevar = params['slide']
  params.each do |k,v|   # with only one, it's equivalent to params['slide']
    v.each do |x|
      sortall.update(:sortorder => x)
      puts x
      puts v.object_id
    end     
  end
end
```

Or you could do this:

```
post '/sort' do
  sortall = Sort.all
  slidevar = params['slide']
  slidevar.each do |x|
    sortall.update(:sortorder => x)
    puts x
  end
end
```

Comment: Getting close! I adjusted the route with your code above at bottom. I've also cleaned up the vars and naming and will stick to these. Sorry bout that it's my way of knowing if I am using the var correctly. 

I also put the Sinatra Route in, its using datamapper and sql

Comment: changing that one var throws an undefined method `each'. The hash and array has not changed and is still the same as superslide from before. Trying out inspect on them right now. No new code sent.

Comment: I'm going to guess that your `params['slide']` is actually a string, not a hash. The String class does not have a method `#each` which would explain the error. Otherwise, it should work with the updated variable names.

Comment: Hmm odd, I posted some class and inspect results above. On a different note how do I paste and format code in these comment boxes? do the backticks have to wrap each line? Or does it need the four spaces still?

Comment: @tripdragon I think I got it. Slight difference between your inspection code and your actual route is the issue.

Comment: That's definitely it for the iteration portion. It's not working on my end yet, I think I need to locate the rows id as well, i'll tinker on.
I'll update the above for others if I get this understood. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you want to do:

but for your desire output this code would work:

```
superslide = {"weee"=>["3", "4", "1", "2"]}


superslide.each do |o|

    ai = superslide['weee']
    ai.each {|x| puts "#{x}\n event"}
end
```

if I understand you this should work:

superslide["weee"].each {|x| datafilenumber.save = x}

It iterates over each elements in the array and saves them.

Comment: Thank you, however, while that outputs outputs it in console, a test on it with an added var print gives me what I have run into before hand. Updated above