# Iterate Datamapper get update individual rows

Tags: sinatra, datamapper

## Trying to itterate the get()

Or I think thats what I want. I to select each row and change it's Sort.sortorder to the array value so I want

```
   sqlite> select * from sorts;
    515|1|2012-02-24T14:44:07-05:00
    516|2|2012-02-24T14:44:07-05:00
    517|3|2012-02-24T14:44:07-05:00
    518|4|2012-02-24T14:44:07-05:00
    sqlite>
```

Test code using racksh with Sinatra boiled down to this so far

```
adkjsd = [1,2,3,4]

adkjsd.each do |jk|
  puts jk + 1
  Sort.all.update(:sortorder => jk) # true updates all rows to 4 the last in the array
  Sort.get(516).update(:sortorder => 0) # only updates that row  
end

Sort.all.update(:sortorder => jk) # true updates all rows to 4 the last in the array
#output
sqlite> select * from sorts;
515|4|2012-02-24T14:44:07-05:00
516|4|2012-02-24T14:44:07-05:00
517|4|2012-02-24T14:44:07-05:00
518|4|2012-02-24T14:44:07-05:00
sqlite> 

Sort.get(516).update(:sortorder => 0) # only updates that row
#output
sqlite> select * from sorts;
515|4|2012-02-24T14:44:07-05:00
516|0|2012-02-24T14:47:03-05:00
517|4|2012-02-24T14:44:07-05:00
518|4|2012-02-24T14:44:07-05:00
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
adkjsd = [1,2,3,4]
Sort.all.each_with_index do |sort, i|
  sort.sortorder = adkjsd[i]
  sort.save
end
```

I'm still using an array there because I don't know if the values you are trying to set will always be the same. If it's just beginning from one up to the number of rows you could do this:

```
Sort.all.each_with_index do |sort, i|
  sort.sortorder = i + 1
  sort.save
end
```

Comment: !!!!! You win a million internets!!!! Thankyou! It's been a learning adventure coupling this with the previous problem in my questions stack. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425096/sinatra-ruby-iterate-over-an-array-in-a-hash-to-send-jquery-sortable-to-database/9426068#comment11918408_9426068
Thank you again!